# Highcharts add left column to grouped data

Tags: angular, highcharts, html-table

)

I want to create gantt diagram using highchars. I want to add one more column to my data.

Expect:

[image: left]

I used this

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/gvaartjes/r0c7Lksu`
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution for you would be to use a grid axis, which allows us to create a bunch of columns on the left side of the chart.

API references:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/gantt/gantt-axis-grid#vertical-axis
https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.grid

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1twLy4ba/

```
yAxis: {
 type: 'category',
 grid: {      
  borderColor: '#3a5d96',      
  columns: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Tasks'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Assignee'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Duration'
    }
  }]
}}
```